# Debugging errors thrown from SilverlightSerializer

Tags: serialization, windows-phone-7

I am using the SilverlightSerilaizer in a WP7 app to serialise a variety of classes to IsolatedStorage.

On Deserialisation I get one of three errors; MemberAccessException, NullReferenceException or ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Any got any pointers as to where to look for solutions to these?

Thanks

Pat

Comment: I'd start by [de]serialising the classes in turn so you can see which class is causing each of the errors. You've not really asking what each of the errors are and likely causes are you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using **set** methods with an access level not equal to public.